# Only first value is added when using array.push in a while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, servicenow

I'm trying to push records from a query to an array, so that I can compare the vaules.
My problem is that I only get the first value 3 times (if the query returns 3 records).

My code:

```js
var array = [];
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
gr.addQuery('scanned_by', gs.getUserID());
gr.query();

while (gr.next()) {
  array.push(gr.room);
}

gs.info(array);
```

The result:

```
a48d92241bafcc108ddd31d8cd4bcb99,a48d92241bafcc108ddd31d8cd4bcb99,a48d92241bafcc108ddd31d8cd4bcb9
```

Comment: What happens if you do `array.push(gr.room.toString())`?

Comment: Maybe adding `gr = gr.next()` after push statement will help?

Comment: How many records are in your gr response? and did you verify the data in the response is not just duplicates?

Comment: @Mathyn, thanks! That solved it.

Comment: It would be nice to know why this is needed. It looks to me like `gr` recycles objects to save on garbage collection, and `gr.next()` just returns the same object each time but mutates it so its string is different. I would hope that this behaviour is documented somewhere, because OP shouldn't be punished for writing perfectly idiomatic-looking code.

Comment: @Jonfo I could add my solution as an answer but honestly I don't know enough about the framework you use to explain WHY this happens. I'll leave actually answering why `toString` helps to someone else.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `array.push(gr.room)` you are pushing a GlideElement onto an array. A GlideElement is an object. So what you are actually doing is pushing the memory address of that object onto your array.

Each time you go around the `while` loop the GlideElement `gr.room` will contain different content, but it is the same object with the same memory address. It would be very inefficient if ServiceNow were to allocate new memory for all the elements in a record every time a new record was read. When the loop ends, your array will contain a bunch of references to the same object, and that object will contain the last value that you read.

The method `getValue` returns a String, so when you write `array.push(gr.getValue("room"))` you are pushing a string value onto your array.

Here are several solutions that will work. What these solutions have in common is that they push a string value (and not a reusable object) onto the array.

- `array.push(gr.getValue("room"));`
- `array.push(gr.room + "");`
- `array.push(gr.room.toString());`
- `array.push(String(gr.room));`

Comment: Thanks for explaining so much in detail.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [];
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
gr.addQuery('scanned_by', gs.getUserID());
gr.query();

while (gr.next()) {
  array.push(gr.getDisplayValue('room'));
}

gs.info(array);
```

You can write `array.push(gr.getDisplayValue('room'))` instead of `array.push(gr.room)`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `array.push(gr.room)` try `array.push(gr.getValue("room"))`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

In palce of array.push(gr.room) use array.push(gr.getValue("room"))

Corrected Code:

```
var array = [];
var gr = new GlideRecord('incident');
gr.addQuery('scanned_by', gs.getUserID());
gr.query();

while (gr.next()) {
  array.push(gr.getValue("room"));
}

gs.info(array);
```

array.push(gr.room) is pushing memory address of object that's why you are getting the same value.